# How to delete records from a data table using data from a column, python flet

Tags: python, datatable, frameworks, record, flet

I want to know how I can delete a record from my table using data from a column, not by number of columns.

this is my table

```
self.tablaCilindros = DataTable(
        columns=[
            DataColumn(Text("id")),
            DataColumn(Text("Empresa")),
            DataColumn(Text("Tamano")),
            DataColumn(Text("Pico")),
            DataColumn(Text("Accion"))
        ],
        rows=[

        ]
    )
```

And I fill it with data from a database

Example I would like to delete a record if its data in the id column is 550

```
def quitar(self, pagee):
    pagee = pagee

    #What this does is eliminate records according to the position 
    #of the row number, and I want it to delete by id that I get in the database

    del self.tablaCilindros.rows[ExampleNumber1]
    pagee.update()
```